# Conditional join in data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following data.table, `dtgrouped2`:

```
     MonthNo Unique Total
 1:       1    AAA    10
 2:       1    BBB     0
 3:       2    CCC     3
 4:       2    DDD     0
 5:       3    AAA     0
 6:       3    BBB    35
 7:       4    CCC    15
 8:       4    AAA     0
 9:       5    BBB    60
10:       5    CCC     0
11:       6    DDD   100
12:       6    AAA     0
```

And another table, `dt2`:

```
     Unique1 StartDate EndDate Amount1 Amount2
1:     AAA        0        1       7       0
3:     AAA        1        2       5       0
2:     AAA        2        4       3       2
```

I want to insert Amount1 and Amount2 from `dt2` to `dtgrouped2` based on the following logic on "Unique" evaluated for each row of `dtgrouped2`:

```
filter(StartDate< MonthNo & EndDate>=MonthNo)
then MAX(EndDate)
then insert Amount1 as Amount1 and Amount2 as Amount2
```

So you can see that the result is different depending on the row. This would be the expected output:

```
Date    MonthNo Unique  Items   Amounts Amount1 Amount2
Jan       1      AAA    x         10        7   0
Jan       1      BBB    y          2        NA  NA
Feb       2      CCC    x          3        NA  NA
Feb       2      DDD    y         15       NA   NA
March     3      AAA    y         20        3   2
March     3      BBB    x         35       NA   NA
April     4      CCC    x         15       NA   NA
April     4      AAA    y         50       3    2
May       5      BBB    x         60      NA    NA
May       5      CCC    y         70      NA    NA
June      6      DDD    x         100     NA    NA
June      6      AAA    y         20       NA   NA
```

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. 1- Where that `Amounts` column came from? How was it populated? (It is not equal to the `Total` column). 2-
 In the 5th row you have wrong values (?) in for `Amount1` and `Amount2`, it should be `5` and `0` respectively. 3 - Why in the last row the `Amount1` and `Amount2` values aren't populated? It should be `3` and `2` respectively, no? Anyway, I think you could use this: `dt2[dtgrouped2, .(Amount1, Amount2), on = .(Unique1 = Unique, StartDate < MonthNo, EndDate <= MonthNo), mult = "last"]` (if I understand the logic correctly).

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are absolutely correct, the logic should have been EndDate >=MonthNo. The results table is just ungrouped, which is the reason for the extra columns. Thank you, I will try this!

Comment: Thank you David, this worked! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest to use non-equi joins combined with `mult = "last"` (in order to capture only the most recent `EndDate`)

```
dtgrouped2[, c("Amount1", "Amount2") := # Assign the below result to new columns in dtgrouped2
              dt2[dtgrouped2, # join
                  .(Amount1, Amount2), # get the column you need
                  on = .(Unique1 = Unique, # join conditions
                         StartDate < MonthNo, 
                         EndDate >= MonthNo), 
                  mult = "last"]] # get always the latest EndDate
dtgrouped2

#     MonthNo Unique Total Amount1 Amount2
#  1:       1    AAA    10       7       0
#  2:       1    BBB     0      NA      NA
#  3:       2    CCC     3      NA      NA
#  4:       2    DDD     0      NA      NA
#  5:       3    AAA     0       3       2
#  6:       3    BBB    35      NA      NA
#  7:       4    CCC    15      NA      NA
#  8:       4    AAA     0       3       2
#  9:       5    BBB    60      NA      NA
# 10:       5    CCC     0      NA      NA
# 11:       6    DDD   100      NA      NA
# 12:       6    AAA     0      NA      NA
```

The reason that you would need to join `dt2[dtgrouped]` first (and not the other way around) is because you want to join `dt2` for each possible value in `dtgrouped`, hence allow multiple values in `dt2` to be joined to `dtgrouped`

Comment: Thanks again, and for the great explanation David, this worked!